# storage size of ‘s’ isn’t known + pointer to pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

Greeting, 
I faced the error of "Assignment_1.c:10:18: error: storage size of ‘s’ isn’t known" I am not expert in using pointer to pointer, I want to have a dynamic sized array of dynamic sized words. Any idea?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100
int size = MAX;
typedef struct{
    int numberOfWords,averageWordLength,id;
    char ** words;      
    }sentence;
void main(){  
    struct sentence s; 
    s.numberOfWords=3;
    s.averageWordLength=5;
    s.id=1;
    s->words= malloc(size * sizeof(s));
    //printf("%s",s.words);
    }
```

Comment: `s->` that's not going to work...

Comment: Nobody is just "an expert in pointers to pointer". You either know C or you don't. Given your use of `void main`, I might suggest you start at something simpler perhaps. Why are you mixing `s.` and `s->`?

Comment: Fix the `s->` thingy, then try `sizeof(sentence)`. Good luck with it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not use typedef for structs unless you are trying to create an opaque type. This is wrong. `struct` is a great hint to C developers. Linus had a good description of this:

> It's a *mistake* to use typedef for structures and pointers. When you
>   see a
>
> vps_t a;
>
> in the source, what does it mean?
>
> In contrast, if it says
>
> struct virtual_container *a;
>
> you can actually tell what "a" is.
>
> Lots of people think that typedefs "help readability". Not so. They
>   are useful only for:
>
> (a) totally opaque objects (where the typedef is actively used to
>   *hide*
>        what the object is).
>
> ```
>  Example: "pte_t" etc. opaque objects that you can only access using
>  the proper accessor functions.
>
>  NOTE! Opaqueness and "accessor functions" are not good in themselves.
>  The reason we have them for things like pte_t etc. is that there
>  really is absolutely _zero_ portably accessible information there.
> ```
>
> (b) Clear integer types, where the abstraction *helps* avoid
>   confusion
>        whether it is "int" or "long".
>
> ```
>  u8/u16/u32 are perfectly fine typedefs, although they fit into
>  category (d) better than here.
>
>  NOTE! Again - there needs to be a _reason_ for this. If something is
>  "unsigned long", then there's no reason to do
> ```
>
> typedef unsigned long myflags_t;
>
> ```
>  but if there is a clear reason for why it under certain circumstances
>  might be an "unsigned int" and under other configurations might be
>  "unsigned long", then by all means go ahead and use a typedef.
> ```
>
> (c) when you use sparse to literally create a *new* type for
>        type-checking.
>
> ...

Do not declare a bunch of variables in a row. You only confuse others by doing that.

And of course you cannot refer to a member field using `.` operator, you have to use `->`. That being said, you code should look something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 100

struct sentence {
    int numberOfWords;
    int averageWordLength;
    int id;
    char **words;
};

int main()
{
    struct sentence s;
    s.numberOfWords = 3;
    s.averageWordLength = 5;
    s.id = 1;
    s.words = malloc(MAX * sizeof(s));
    /* printf("%s",s.words); */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Also consider having `words as the first member of the structure or you waste memory due to misalignment on platforms where alignment of a pointer is greater than integer.

Answer (score 0):

Use '->' when the structure's object is a pointer type. This should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100
int size = MAX;
typedef struct{
  int numberOfWords,averageWordLength,id;
  char *words;
}sentence;

void main(){
  sentence s;
  s.numberOfWords=3;
  s.averageWordLength=5;
  s.id=1;
  s.words= malloc(size * sizeof(s));
  //printf("%s",s.words);
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(1024)`?  Try again.  Also, he clearly wants the allocated size to depend on the variable `size`.

Comment: Thanks @MooingDuck! Hope this suffices. Although, the above answers are better :)

Answer (score -1):

In

```
typedef struct {
    int numberOfWords, averageWordLength, id;
    char **words;
    } sentence;
```

you create a unnamed struct and an alias for that struct. The alias name is `sentence`.

You now have a new type in your code. The new type name is `sentence`. If you provided a tag there would be 2 new type names: `sentence` and `struct tag`.

```
typedef struct tag {
    whatever;
} sentence;
```

Also note the typedef isn't really needed

```
struct tag {
    whatever;
};
```

The snippet above defines a new type named `struct tag`.